# How to make .NET Code Output Smaller Binaries

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, async-await, binaries

I'm working on a UWP app where it's important to reduce the size of the app. Recently, I discovered that simply adding 6 `await` statements increased the `.dll` size by 20KB which I thought was an unexpectedly large amount but made sense when I realized that `async`/`await` generates a lot of state machine code.

What techniques or patterns are available in C# and .NET Core to reduce the size of my binaries? I'm assuming that code reuse would be high up on that list.

Comment: [Don't ask about .... **Requests for lists of things,** polls, **opinions,** discussions, etc.](https://stackoverflow.com/tour/)

Comment: A far as techniques, start disassembling your output code into IL (for example with ILSpy, where you can easily switch between C# and IL views) and compare different ways of doing the same thing and how much code they end up generating.  Like in most cases, a "for" is going to be smaller than a "foreach" loop, because foreach does stuff behind the scenes for you.  A lot of things that make your life easier as a programmer will end up making the code bigger.

Comment: problem with UWP is that in fact it is compiled to native

Comment: interesting question, but I guess there is not so much experience of .NET native out there?!